# Add an asterisk in front of section label in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

Could you please tell me how to make the table of content like this:

> Preface..................................i
>
> Chapitre 1. Les décisions ................1
>
> 1.1 Bla bla bla ........................6
>
> 1.2 Bla bla bla ........................7
>
> Chapitre 2. Les conférence ...............10
>
> 2.1 Bla bla bla ........................16
>
> *2.2 Bla bla bla ........................17
>
> 2.3 Bla bla bla ........................19
>
> *2.4 Bla bla bla ........................21
>
> 2.5 Bla bla bla ........................25
>
> Conclusion ...............................30
>
> Appendix A ...............................35
>
> Bibliographie ............................40

The section 2.2 and 2.4 prefix an asterisk to denote a `hard` level. The header mark is same as in TOC.

Comment: You can have a look at the `tocloft` package to modify the table of contents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this is to create an environment that changes the format of the section number.  Then a bit of `tocloft` magic will make the TOC entries look nice.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\newenvironment{hard}
{\renewcommand{\thesection}{*\thechapter.\arabic{section}}}
{}
% set section numbers in TOC flush right (from the tocloft documentation)
\newlength{\extralen}
\setlength{\extralen}{0.5em}    % need some extra space at end of number
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\hfill} % note the double ‘l’ 
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\hspace*{\extralen}}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{\extralen}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A regular section}\label{easylabel}
In Section~\ref{easylabel} we see\ldots
\lipsum
\begin{hard}
\section{A hard section}\label{hardlabel}
\lipsum
\end{hard}
In Section~\ref{hardlabel} we see\ldots
\end{document}
```

Note that this solution will also make the section number in references have an *, and subsections within a hard section will also bear an *.  (For subsections you'll also need to add the appropriate `tocloft` code to make their numbers flush right as well.)  If you don't want that, then things get a bit more complicated.

[image: Table of contents from code]

Comment: @Stufazi If the solution worked for you, and you consider your question answered, then you should click on the checkmark icon next to the answer to accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.4171 ...n{Extensiones inseparables} \lipsum \end
                                                  {hard}
? 
! Emergency stop. Why is this?

Comment: Since the example works for me and for others, there must be something else going on. Are you trying to compile this *exact* example?

Comment: "Note that this solution will also make the section number in references have an * [...] If you don't want that, then things get a bit more compicated."

Do you have a solution for that ? I tried to create a copy of section by tweaking things like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31780/where-can-i-find-help-files-or-documentation-for-commands-like-startsection-fo and by redefining a copy of the definition of `\part`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that looks pretty much like what you want, but will not number the hard section in the document. For that, you might want to tune with `titlesec` to format your headings:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\hardsection}[1]{%
   \section*{#1}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{$^*$~\thesection~#2}
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section*{A section here}
\lipsum

\hardsection{And a hard section there}
\lipsum

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section*{And another section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \optionalsection.