# Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like \@startsection for LaTeX?

Tags: sectioning, documentation, latex-base

I can't find official documentation for the `\@startsection` command.
I already looked in:

1. LaTeX Wikibook
2. LaTeX: Structured document for TEX, 2008
3. beginLatex — a book that comes with ProTeX
4. in the files that comes with MikTeX in the folder `doc`

and Google.
I found a lot of sites that show examples and discussions about it but I'd like to find the official help or document.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The actual command, including its formal definition posted by @JoshLee is contained in the [LaTeX 2e source](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf), section **61.2 Sectioning** (p 283). It forms part of [`ltsect.dtx`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/ltsect.dtx), the bundle containing all sectioning commands for LaTeX. It even includes a pseudo-code interpretation of the actual macro. Here is an extract:

> The
>   `\@startsection{<name>}{<level>}{<indent>}{<beforeskip>}{<afterskip>}{<style>}*[<altheading>]{<heading>}`
>   command is the mother of all the user level sectioning commands. The
>   part after the `*`, including the `*` is optional.
>
> - **name**: e.g., `subsection`
> - **level**: a number, denoting depth of section - e.g., `chapter` = 0, `section` = 1, etc.
> - **indent**: Indentation of heading from left margin
> - **beforeskip**: Absolute value = skip to leave above the heading. If negative, then paragraph indent of text following heading is
>     suppressed.
> - **afterskip**: If positive, then skip to leave below heading, else negative of skip to leave to right of run-in heading.
> - **style**: Commands to set style. Since June 1996 release the *last* command in this argument may be a command such as `\MakeUppercase` or
>     `\fbox` that takes an argument. The section heading will be supplied
>     as the argument to this command. So setting `#6` to, say,
>     `\bfseries\MakeUppercase` would produce bold, uppercase headings.
>
> If `*` is missing, then increment the counter. If it is present, then
>   there should be no `[<altheading>]` argument. The command uses the
>   counter `secnumdepth`. It contains a pointer to the highest section
>   level that is to be numbered.

Comment: Excellent that is exactly what I want. Let's read!

Comment: Can anyone help explain to me the use `\@plus` and `\@minus` in this context `\@startsection{subexperiment}{2}{\z@} {1ex \@plus 2ex \@minus 0.5ex}{1.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\normalsize\nobreak}
         {#1}`

Comment: @George: `\@plus` and `\@minus` are similar to `\plus` and `\minus` and refer to *glue*. See [What is glue stretching?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64756/5764)

Comment: It seems \@startsection messes up \leftmark and \rightmark. What is the easiest way to prevent this)

Comment: @Alberto: In what way? Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your issues?

Comment: I think this should be some kind of interference from some packages I am using, like bidi...

Comment: @Werner, there is no mention to `\addcontentsline{toc}` as in `\@chapter` for example. So, how the section goes to contents?

Comment: @Sigur: There is `\addcontentsline{toc}` in `\@chapter` in [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) (if you're using `\chapter`s). Also, there is `\addcontentsline{toc}` in `\@sect` in [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) (if you're using `\section`s and below). `\@sect` is the macro called by `\@startsection` if you're setting a numbered section. If you're setting an unnumbered section, it calls `\@ssect` and no ToC entry is set.

Comment: @Werner, so `\@sect` is what I have to look for. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

It’s not a LaTeX command *per se* (which is why it’s not well documented), but a TeX macro that’s defined in the implementation of LaTeX’s kernel. @Concerned has a good answer, but you can also explore macros in LaTeX’s interactive mode:

```
~$ latex
**\makeatletter
*\show\@startsection
> \@startsection=macro:
#1#2#3#4#5#6->\if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi \par \@tempskipa #4\relax
\@afterindenttrue \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@ \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse \fi
\if@nobreak \everypar {}\else \addpenalty \@secpenalty \addvspace \@tempskipa \fi
\@ifstar {\@ssect {#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}{\@dblarg {\@sect {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}.
```

Comment: Great comment. I didn't know about that. Does it also work after including packages to get more information about in-package defined macros?

Comment: Yep. `\section`, for example, doesn't exist until you include the document class.

Comment: Actually, using `texdoc packagename` (or `texdoc source2e` for the kernel) will often give better results, as it also contains clarification for the commands.

Answer (score 9):

I'd consider the [LaTeX companion (second edition)](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/books.html) as a very good ressource for this kind of command. It may be not up to date in every aspect, but IMO very much is still valid.

Comment: It's the second book every LaTeX user should have. The first one should be Lamport's.

Comment: And en passant, you will NOT find it in Formatting Information (beginlatex, see http://latex.silmaril.ie/) as that's aimed more at complete beginners, and \@startsection is a bit more advanced than that.

Answer (score 5):

look into the main LaTeX file `latex.ltx`. You'll find it in the `tex/latex/base` directory, or let `kpsewhich` find the place:

```
kpsewhich latex.ltx
```

For my system:

```
voss@shania:~> kpsewhich latex.ltx
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
```

in this file you'll find *all* definitions.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of LaTex's internals can be mastered only by using the source, but have a look at [LaTeX 2e for Class and Package Writers](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

See [This discussion on the texhax mailing list](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2006-June/006375.html) for where to find the definition in the LaTeX distribution  [This link](http://www.langbein.org/publish/latex/latex-7.pdf) (PDF) has some documentation about it.