# hyperref using ref: How can I avoid the section number

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

```
perf~\ref{soft_reset_perf}

\phantomsection
\item[perf]:~\label{soft_reset_perf} Indicates that a soft reset has been performed.
```

It shows next to 'perf' the section number. How can I just get a link without section number?

With `~\nameref{soft_reset_perf}` I get the name of the section in which the label is defined. I want the item name ('perf' in this case) to be displayed instead of the section name.

Comment: If you want to refer to an item in a list why don't you simply use cross-reference by `\ref`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) chandras! Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412414/hyperref-using-ref-how-can-i-avoid-the-section-number?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one alternative to achieve your output. Since you're after referencing the name of a label, using a sectional unit is ideal.

In the example below, I've defined `\Item` to be similar to `\paragraph` (it is set at the "paragraph level" with some spacing adjustments) in the sense that it is now a sectional unit. As such, using `\label{<lab>}` and `\nameref{<lab>}` works as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Item{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{-2em}%
                               {0pt}%
                               {0pt}%
                               {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

For more information, see~\nameref{soft_reset_perf} or~\nameref{something}.

\begingroup
\setlength{\leftskip}{2em}% Correct for \Item adjustment
\Item{perf}:~\label{soft_reset_perf} Indicates that a soft 
  reset has been performed. Here is some more text. Here is some 
  more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text.
\Item{something}:~\label{something} This is just an interesting 
  item that will be referenced by name at a different location in 
  the document.\par
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

To mimic an `itemize` environment, I've typeset the `\Item` with a `2em` negative indent (undent?). As such, to correct for horizontal shift, the left margin has been pushed right by `2em` (by setting `\leftskip`). For help on the specific components in the definition of `\Item`, consider reading [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like \@startsection for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31780/where-can-i-find-help-files-or-documentation-for-commands-like-startsection-fo)

Although I've used [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref), it works just as well with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}

For more information, see~\nameref{soft_reset_perf} or~\nameref{something}.

\paragraph{perf}:~\label{soft_reset_perf} Indicates that a soft 
  reset has been performed. Here is some more text. Here is some 
  more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text.
\paragraph{something}:~\label{something} This is just an interesting 
  item that will be referenced by name at a different location in 
  the document.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In principle, how is this different from my answer?