# Enumerate content and reference the numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, paragraphs

I'm looking for a solution to enumerate paragraphs in my appendix and reference the numbers. I don't want to use sections for it and the `enumerate` environment seems unfeasible.

In my case I have around 40 statements that I want to enumerate and each statement has some describing text and formulas.

Comment: Why is using the enumerate environment unfeasible?

Comment: isn't it more for smaller content like lists?

Comment: What goes wrong if you use it for this?

Comment: You can use `subsection` or `subsubsection` or `paragraph`

Comment: I am not really sure what you are exactly asking but if you just want to number paragraphs the easiest solution is just with the \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}  but that then \paragraph{example} becomes 1.1.1.1 example

Comment: Upvote for  Ian Thompson, I just used enumerate

Answer (score 5):

Without a specific example I can only provide general help. One case of this is covered [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=10815) where the author would like to number different 'phases'. The code boils down to:

```
\newcounter{phase} \setcounter{phase}{0}
\renewcommand{\thephase}{\Roman{phase}}
\newcommand{\phase}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{phase}%
    \textbf{Phase} \thephase: \texttt{#1}
}

\phase{blah}\label{pha:foo}
Look, Mom, a reference to \ref{pha:foo}!
```

Comment: There are some problems with your code: the `\label` will produce *two* spaces in output.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to re-purpose `\paragraph` for this using the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}% Allow up to \paragraph enumeration
\begin{document}
\section{A section} Here is some text.
\paragraph{Some text} Here is some more text.
\paragraph{} Here is some final text.
\end{document}
```

Setting `secnumdepth` to `4` allows for "level 4" sectioning commands to be numbered (which holds for `\paragraph`). More detail on the possible changes:

- `\z@` (`0pt`) refers to the indentation from the left margin;
- `3.25ex`... refers to the space (and glue) inserted *before* the heading;
- `-1em` refers to the space *after* the heading. If its negative, no line break will occur, while a positive length inserts a vertical skip;
- `\normalfont`... refers to the font of the `\paragraph` argument.

You can modify it to avoid using an argument by including it as part of the definition. For more information on `\@startsection`, see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{Specification \arabic{enumi}: }}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm,itemindent=.5cm,labelwidth=\itemindent,labelsep=0cm,align=left]

\item XY mus hold

Some explanation

\begin{equation}
A = B + C
\end{equation}

%% Next item ...

\end{enumerate}
```

Because I splitted the items into several files I use `resume` to continue my enumeration:

```
\begin{enumerate}[resume, leftmargin=0cm,itemindent=.5cm,labelwidth=\itemindent,labelsep=0cm,align=left]

\end{enumerate}
```

With this I can reference formulas and equations everywhere in my document.