# Sectioning in letter-type documents

Tags: sectioning, letters, newlfm

I want to use sectioning in letters (`section`, `subsection`, etc), but [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_Commands) I read that basically all of these sectioning commands do not apply to letters. What is the proper way to create sections in letters?

Using: `documentclass[stdletter]{newlfm}`

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: Sorry, not mentioned -- added now!

Comment: 'etc.'?  How many sectional levels will this letter need?  And do you need to emulate simply the look/style of different sections (bold, large, small caps, etc.), which would be easy enough, or do you need them to do all the things normal sectional divisions do (numbered, unnumbered, in ToC, not in ToC), which would require a more involved solution.

Comment: The `newlfm` document class does not offer a `\subsection` command, and even the `\section` command is implemented in a rather rudimentay way, as `\newcommand{\section}[1]{{\Large {\bfseries #1}}}`. This is not surprising given that this document class is meant to be used for letters, memos, and faxes. If you absolutely must use a second-level sectioning command, you could set `\newcommand{\subsection}[1]{{\large {\bfseries #1}}}`. Note, though, that no provisions exist for any kind of numbering of these sectioning commands, and the spacing above and below the headers will likely be poor.

Comment: I only needed this to visually achieve something similar to the section & subsection headers. I've used the newcommand function to get this done. Thanks all!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's one possible solution, using the kernel command `\@startsection` (you chan find a description of this command in [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like \@startsection for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/3954)) to redefine the `\section` command (the `newlfm` class offers a very basic `\section` command) and define the `\subsection` command to behave as those from `article.cls`. Basically, all you have to do is to define the counters and use `\@startsection` with appropriate settings. A simple example:

```
\documentclass[stdletter]{newlfm}

\newcounter{section}
\newcounter{subsection}[section]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand \thesection{\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\section{Test Section Two}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The previous solution doen't make provissions for a ToC, but this is also really simple: all one has to do is to define `\tableofcontents` using `\@starttoc` and define `\l@section`, `\l@subsection` to typeset the corresponding entries.

Answer (score 17):

You have already accepted an answer, but I give you another option:

You can use `scrlttr2` from the [KOMAscript-bundle](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), and by by loading the letter class option file, `section.lco`, you will have sectioning commands. The appearance of the sections can be modified by standard `komascript`-commands. The .LCO also handles sections with star (`\section*{Test}`. `section.lco` gives you four levels of headings.

You can download `section.lco` [from KOMAscript’s homepage.](http://www.komascript.de/sections.lco#attachments) Put `section.lco` in your `local-texmf`, and remember to update the file database.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\LoadLetterOption{sections}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Name of Recipient \\ Address \\ of \\ Recipient}

\setkomavar{subject}{This is a strict formal letter}

\opening{}  % eg. Hello

\section{Section one}
\blindtext

\subsection{Subsection also}
\blindtext

\section{Section two}
\blindtext

\closing{Kind regards} %eg. Regards

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```