# Changing the section title

Tags: sectioning

```
\section{Introduction}
```

gives something like

## 1. Introduction

How can I rather obtain the following header?

## Section 1. Introduction

Comment: For example: `\def\thesection{Section~\arabic{section}.}`

Comment: Should this *only* affect the section title as it's set, and not the reference? What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @Werner: I use the \documentclass{article}. There is no table of content, so it should only affect the section title. Thanks! I will try Eddy_Em' solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and within the default document classes, you could patch `\@sect` to conditionally insert `Section~` based on whether you are in `\section` or not:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {\relax\@svsec}% <search>
  {\relax\ifnum#2=1\relax Section~\fi\@svsec}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{section}
\subsection{A subsection}
See Section~\ref{section}.
\end{document}
```

The patch is provided by [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd`. It searches fo `\relax\@svsec` and inserts the condition inbetween. The condition checks if the level of the sectional unit matches "level 1" (that of `\section`), as is the case when looking at the definition in [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) (the second argument to `\@startsection`):

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

For detail on the components of `\@startsection`, see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764)

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I follow what the purpose of `\@svsec` is.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a very useful feature of TeX; a command called as

```
\csname foo\endcsname
```

will be silently ignored (actually `\relax` would be executed, which does nothing) if `\foo` isn't defined.

So doing

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname named#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\namedsection}{Section }

\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{section}
\subsection{A subsection}
See Section~\ref{section}.
\end{document}
```

you reach your aim.

[image]

If you also want to add "Subsection" in front of the subsection number, just add

```
\newcommand{\namedsubsection}{Subsection }
```

The macro `\@seccntformat` is described, with similar tricks, in the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes), see [Adjusting the presentation of section numbers](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-seccntfmt)