# Change the numbering of a section

Tags: sectioning

All I want is a simple thing:
Change the section numbering to become like this

```
1.  Introduction
```

And not the default, where there is no point. I also want to make the point appear for the `subsection` and the `subsubsection`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I've found the solution on this link, if somebody is interested, please visite the link here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96692/changing-the-section-title do as it is mentionned, but just write this : \def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad} instead of what's written there.
P.-S: i'm new to the formum, so i'll try to be more concise in the future, appreciate your help.

Comment: @zine Since it seems that you are just beginning with LaTeX you might be better off using the package based solution in my answer or in the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to change section headings in the standard document classes is with the `titlesec` package:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
```

If you are using  the KOMA classes, you can set this as a class option:

```
\documentclass[numbers=endperiod]{scratcl}
```

Comment: Wow, almost an [exact duplicate of your other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24440/5764)...

Comment: @werner I couldn't find the duplicate... :)

Comment: Thank you very much Alan. Simply, i wasn't expecting such a community. I'm just on the way to discover its charm, your solution was simple and very awesome.