# Where's the extra vertical space coming from in my section definition

Tags: spacing, macros, sectioning

Along the lines of similar questions on this site, e.g.:

[Changing the section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96692/changing-the-section-title)

I wanted to define a custom, section-like structure of my own -- `\unit` -- which would be similar to a section. However, I actually wanted it to have the font size and spacing above and below it of `subsection` in the default `article` class (because it is at subsection level in my document). I also wanted a `\subunit` to go underneath it.

Now I know I could have modified `\section` and `\subsection` with `titlesec` or whatever, but I wasn't very interested in that, because I wanted to keep `\section` and `\subsection` and have another, independent set of structures, `\unit` and `\subunit`.

So what I did was to simply take the standard definition of `\subsection` in `article.cls`:

```latex
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

And use it to define `unit`. Ditto for `\subsubsection` and `\subunit`:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcounter{unit}
\newcounter{subunit}[unit]

\renewcommand{\theunit}{\arabic{unit}}
\renewcommand{\thesubunit}{\theunit.\arabic{subunit}}

\newcommand\unit{\@startsection{unit}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}

\newcommand\subunit{\@startsection{subunit}{2}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\let\unitmark\@gobble
\let\subunitmark\@gobble
\makeatother
```

I was feeling quite pleased with myself, but then I decided to modify my definition of `unit` (only) to put the word Unit before the number and a colon afterwards, i.e.:

**Unit 1: Normal Working**

This is definitely something I'd like to be able to do elsewhere and I'm not the only one, I think. It'd be nice to easily be able to produce section headings along the lines of Exercise 1, Question 1 and even Chapter 1 if you don't want the full blown chapter style of the `report` class.

So what I resorted to doing was delving into the internals of `\@startsection` and re-implementing them, hard coding the parameters I'd decided on and getting rid of all the unnecessary `\if \fi`s, since I wasn't defining an ultra-generic structure, but a specific instantiation.

That led me to this:

```latex
\newcommand\unit[1]{%
  \par
  \@tempskipa -3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex\relax
  \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \refstepcounter{unit}%
  \begingroup
    \normalfont\large\bfseries{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip \z@\relax Unit~\theunit:\space}%
        \interlinepenalty \@M #1\@@par}%
  \endgroup
  \@xsect{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}}
```

Which is the result of taking the definitions of `\@startsection` and `\@sect` from `latex.ltx`

```latex
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}
```

And, as I say, putting in values and getting rid of unnecessary `\if` statements and alternatives I won't be using.

## The Problem

The problem is, the new version of `\unit` produces excess vertical space above the heading, as you can see if you compare the output of the two.

### Code for output on left

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{unit}
\newcounter{subunit}[unit]

\renewcommand{\theunit}{\arabic{unit}}
\renewcommand{\thesubunit}{\theunit.\arabic{subunit}}

\newcommand\unit{\@startsection{unit}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
% \newcommand\unit[1]{%
%   \par
%   \@tempskipa -3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex\relax
%   \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
%   \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
%   \refstepcounter{unit}%
%   \begingroup
%     \normalfont\large\bfseries{%
%       \@hangfrom{\hskip \z@\relax Unit~\theunit:\space}%
%         \interlinepenalty \@M #1\@@par}%
%   \endgroup
%   \@xsect{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}}
\newcommand\subunit{\@startsection{subunit}{2}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\let\unitmark\@gobble
\let\subunitmark\@gobble
\makeatother

\title{Log Book}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Activity Log}

\unit{Normal Working}

\subunit{Shift handover}

A good shift handover includes discussion of the past, present and future: what
has happened, what is happening now, what might happen in future.

\end{document}
```

### Code for output on right

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{unit}
\newcounter{subunit}[unit]

\renewcommand{\theunit}{\arabic{unit}}
\renewcommand{\thesubunit}{\theunit.\arabic{subunit}}

% \newcommand\unit{\@startsection{unit}{1}{\z@}%
%   {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
%   {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
%   {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\unit[1]{%
  \par
  \@tempskipa -3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex\relax
  \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \refstepcounter{unit}%
  \begingroup
    \normalfont\large\bfseries{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip \z@\relax Unit~\theunit:\space}%
        \interlinepenalty \@M #1\@@par}%
  \endgroup
  \@xsect{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}}
\newcommand\subunit{\@startsection{subunit}{2}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\let\unitmark\@gobble
\let\subunitmark\@gobble
\makeatother

\title{Log Book}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Activity Log}

\unit{Normal Working}

\subunit{Shift handover}

A good shift handover includes discussion of the past, present and future: what
has happened, what is happening now, what might happen in future.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your cleanup of `\@startsection`, this conditional:

```latex
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
```

evaluates to true, thus `\everypar{}`. In your code you used the false branch, thus the difference.

But I invite you to reconsider your approach. Stripping down `\@startsection` and its subordinates will, for starters, make `hyperref` not work with your newly-defined sections (`hyperref` patches `\@startsection`).

Instead, you can redefine `\theunit` and `\thesubunit` to print the section headings with the format you want:

```latex
\renewcommand{\theunit}{Unit~\arabic{unit}:\space}
\renewcommand{\thesubunit}{Subunit~\arabic{unit}.\arabic{subunit}:\space}
```

Also, if you want the `\quad` space after `\thesection` but not after `\theunit`, you can redefine `\@seccntformat` to check for that with a little help from `expl3` (could be done without `expl3`, but why? ;-)

```latex
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \StrCaseF \str_case:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \StrCaseF{#1}{{unit}{}{subunit}{}}{\quad}% To remove \quad from \unit and \subunit
}
```

With that, the output looks like what you want:

> [image]

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{unit}
\newcounter{subunit}[unit]

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \StrCaseF \str_case:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\theunit}{Unit~\arabic{unit}:\space}
\renewcommand{\thesubunit}{Subunit~\arabic{unit}.\arabic{subunit}:\space}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \StrCaseF{#1}{{unit}{}{subunit}{}}{\quad}% To remove \quad from \unit and \subunit
}

\newcommand\unit{\@startsection{unit}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subunit{\@startsection{subunit}{2}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\let\unitmark\@gobble
\let\subunitmark\@gobble
\makeatother

\title{Log Book}
\date{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Activity Log}

\unit{Normal Working}

\subunit{Shift handover}

A good shift handover includes discussion of the past, present and future: what
has happened, what is happening now, what might happen in future.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I thought I had tried the `\everypar{}` branch, but the thing is I tried that and it didn't work, then I tried something else and that didn't work, but obviously I needed to try both of them together! I didn't know I was breaking `hyperref` and I'm happy to hear about better solutions, but are there any side effects to your alternative? If not, then I'm really quite tempted by it.

Comment: I have a lot of time for the basic classes and the basic sectioning commands provided by them, but I've long been a proponent of LaTeX's define a complex structure at the start and then use that and you can redefine it at will if you change a design choice. And as I say the basics are good enough in most cases, but I've long thought it'd be good to have a way to easily 'roll your own'. Customising, for example, `section` is quite easy with `titlesec`, but defining totally separate structures seems quite tricky. And the question 1, section 1, exercise 1, etc. style is something i've long wanted

Comment: @Au101 You will not _break_ `hyperref` (since you are not changing `\@startsection` itself), but `hyperref`'s hyprelinking features will not work for `\(sub)unit`, because it doesn't know it has to patch (neither _how_ to patch) `\(sub)unit`. As far as I can see, there is no issue with the solution I proposed: `\the(sub)unit` and `\@seccntformat` are customisation points, so it's okay to redefine them. That's how I'd do it.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Au101 About LaTeX's design: its current appearance is essentially a backwards compatibility to Lamport's LaTeX, which dates back to the 90s or earlier. We can't change anything there without breaking the documents of hundreds (if not thousands) of users. The LaTeX3 project's aim is to provide an actual typesetting system based on document elements and how the document designer would put them, with no strings attached to LaTeX's original layout (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46427/134574)). We just lack the manpower to do all that :-)

Comment: Well I know nothing of LaTeX3 you see, I had looked at dabbling with `\@seccntformat`, but I didn't know how to tweak that just for `unit` and `subunit` without it altering `section` and friends, anyway, let's not start a comment thread down here