# KOMA-Script scrreprt: Section numbering and heading embodied into the first line of text

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

Using KOMA-Script package `scrreprt` I need to have the section numbering and heading included in the first paragraph of the section itself and the numbering of sections restarting from each chapter, i.e.:
instead of

**Chapter 1**

**Rome**

**1.1 The Magic Of Rome**

Ibam forte via sacra.............

**1.2 Modern Rome**

Andavo per caso per la via sacra .......

**Chapter 2**

**Milan**

**2.1 Is Milan magic?**

Ibam forte via sacra.............

**2.2 Modern Milan**

Andavo per caso per la via sacra .......

===========:==========
***I would like to have:***

**Chapter 1**

**Rome**

**1.The magic of Rome.** Ibam forte via sacra.............

**2.Modern Rome.** Andavo per caso per la via sacra .......

**Chapter 2**

**Milan**

**1.Is Milan magic.** Ibam forte via sacra.............

**2.Modern Milan.** Andavo per caso per la via sacra .......

How can I obtain this result?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you use such a numbering scheme you can't work with hyperlinks. The number of the sections is always equal.

Answer (score 6):

Three things are important to obtain this result:

1. Remove the chapter numbering component from that of the section numbering:

   ```
   \renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
   ```
2. Update the `\section` command to allow text to follow in-line with the title (a so-called run-in header). This depends on the fifth argument (or **afterskip**) to `\@startsection`. This value has to be negative. The default definition for `\section` is:

   ```
   \newcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
     {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
     {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
     {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
       \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
       \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
   }
   ```

   where **afterskip** is given as `2.3ex \@plus.2ex` (positive). We update this to now be

   ```
   \renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
     {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
     {-2.3ex \@plus-.2ex}%{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
     {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
       \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
       \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
   }
   ```

   where **afterskip** is now `-2.3ex \@plus-.2ex` (negative).

   For a reference, see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764)
3. Force a period `.` after sectioning levels using

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[3]{#3.\enskip}
   ```

   The above also adds an `\enskip`, which you could remove if needed.

Here's a complete MWE containing the above modifications:

[image]

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {-2.3ex \@plus-.2ex}%{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[3]{#3.\enskip}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Rome}
\section{Magic of Rome}
Ibam forte via sacra \ldots
\section{Modern Rome}
Andavo per caso per la via sacra \ldots
\chapter{Milan}
\section{Is Milan magic?}
Ibam forte via sacra \ldots
\section{Modern Milan}
Andavo per caso per la via sacra \ldots
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must redefine the counter `\thesection`

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Rome}
\section{Magic of Rome}
Ibam forte via sacra \ldots
\section{Modern Rome}
Andavo per caso per la via sacra \ldots
\chapter{Milan}
\section{Is Milan magic?}
Ibam forte via sacra \ldots
\section{Modern Milan}
Andavo per caso per la via sacra \ldots
\end{document}
```

here the result:

[image]