# Decreasing space between subsubsections

Tags: spacing, sectioning, document-classes, lncs

I use the [LNCS](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) document style for a paper. However, I find the spacing between subsubsections (ca 2 lines) very generous and would like to decrease it. How can I do this? (Note: I am not required to adhere to the LNCS formatting rules, so hacking this is okay.)

```
%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[10pt,english]{llncs}
\begin{document}
\section{Section A}
\subsubsection{First.}
Lorem ipsum.
% TODO: decrease spacing here
\subsubsection{Second.}
Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've been around long enough to know that even the slightest bit of effort in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) goes a looooong way. Sorry to harp on it, but like gravity, I wish it was the law.

Comment: What exactly would a MWE for this case contain? The answer might be very general.

Comment: From your code it's clear that you use [LyX](http://www.lyx.org), but also that you don't seem to be using any packages dealing with sectioning (like [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) or [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), say). That is what the MWE tells me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space *above* `\subsubsection` is similar to that above a `\subsection` and `\section`, according to [`llncs.cls`](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip). You need to update the lengths to your liking:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}% http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Some text
\subsection{A subsection}
Some text
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
Some text
\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
Some text

\bigskip

% Put the block below in your LaTeX preamble
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                       {-8\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}% Formerly -18\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@
                       {-0.5em \@plus -0.22em \@minus -0.1em}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}
\makeatother

\section{A section}
Some text
\subsection{A subsection}
Some text
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
Some text
\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
Some text
\end{document}
```

The change was made to the arguments of `\@startsection`, which is called by `\subsubsection` (and most other sectioning macros). Specifically, the fourth and fifth argument deal with the space before and after the sectioning command. If it's negative (as is the case with `\subsubsection`), a run-in title is produced, otherwise it is set as a display. For more on the actual meaning/usage, see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764)