# Cyrillic \MakeUppercase

Tags: sectioning, capitalization, cyrillic

`\MakeUppercase` does not capitalize Cyrillic fonts.

I am trying to create a custom document class which would write the section titles in upper case. For this purpose I use the solution provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31795/16578). However, it turned out that the `\MakeUppercase` command capitalizes the Latin letters only. All the Cyrillic letters are left intact. It looks like this:

> FIRST SECTION - Первый раздел

This is true not only for the section headings, but for a regular text also. So the command:

```
\MakeUppercase{English text. Русский текст.}
```

produces the following output:

> ENGLISH TEXT. Русский текст.

What could be the reason for such behaviour and how can I solve this issue?

Note: I use **pdflatex** to compile the document.

---

Here is the simplest working example to start with:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{English Text. Русский текст.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't mention which engine you're using: the mechanism is different according to whether you're using (pdf)latex or (xe|lua)tex.  (also, people's lives are improved if you provide a minimal working example.  it's trivial in this case, but _they're_ the ones helping _you_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the line

```
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
```

in the preamble so to have the right font encodings.

Thus the MWE

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{English Text. Русский текст.}
\end{document}
```

yields the desired result

[image]

P.S.: The `T1` option is not needed if you use only Russian in your document.

Comment: `T1` is not needed if only Russian is used. Strangely enough, the `russian` option issues a message saying that `T2A` is used, but probably something goes wrong; loading the `fontenc` indeed solves the issue.

Comment: @egreg, I know. I added `T1` seeing that OP uses also English. Thanks (as usual) for your remarks.