# How to disable indentation in subsubsection using IEEEtran?

Tags: sectioning, indentation, ieeetran, sections-paragraphs

I am using `IEEEtran` and my sub subsections are indented. I tried using `\parindent0pt` but that removes the indentation of the paragraphs too. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you're preparing a document for submission, don't bother with these problems: the journal or conference copy editors will just be annoyed by these layout changes.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Remember that [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3):

[`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) creates the sectional units via `\@startsection`, but it depends on the mode you're calling the class with. Only under `journal` (default), `conference` or `transmag` will `\subsubsection` have an indent. And, based on the fact that you have a problem *only* with `\subsubsection`, it seems like you're running `IEEEtran` under `journal` (default) or `conference`. Here's the definition of `\subsubsection` under these modes (taken from [`IEEEtran.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls)):

```
% journal and conference
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}% name
                                 {3}% level
                                 {\parindent}% indent
                                 {0ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}% before skip
                                 {0ex}% after skip
                                 {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}% style
```

The third argument (`\parindent`) gives the indent associated with the sectional unit (see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764)). If you want to remove it, redefine `\subsubsection` in the same way except with a zero (or `\z@`) indent:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran

\makeatletter
% journal (default) and conference
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}% name
                                 {3}% level
                                 {\z@}% indent (formerly \parindent)
                                 {0ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}% before skip
                                 {0ex}% after skip
                                 {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}% style
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All I get is errors when I try this.