# Adjusting spacing before and after subparagraph with sectsty

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, titlesec, sections-paragraphs, sectsty

I am helping a friend that is using `sectsty` to format the titles in his document. How can I adjust the spacing before and after the titles, in particular the `subparagraph` one?

(I know that `titlesec` is more powerful. But for now we just need either a quick fix or the full translation of the following to `titlesec`.)

This is what we have now:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering\normalfont\normalsize}
\subsectionfont{\noindent\normalfont\normalsize\emph}
%\subsubsectionfont{\indent\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}
\subparagraphfont{\indent\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}
```

As usual this is because of thesis requirements made by ignorant people.

Comment: *Always* post [complete examples](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than code snippets, please!

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: `apa6`, I'll post a complete example when I have access to the original document.

Answer (score 6):

[`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) only updates only the sectional unit *font*-related setting but still use the traditional `\@startsection` construction:

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
      {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
%     {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\SS@sectfont}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
      {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
%     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
      {\normalfont\large\bfseries\SS@subsectfont}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
      {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
%     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@subsubsectfont}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
      {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
      {-1em}%
%     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@parafont}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
      {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
      {-1em}%
%     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@subparafont}}
```

The normal font-selections are commented out and substituted with the `sectsty` formatting `\SS@...`. Read up on the meaning of each component of `\@startsection` in [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764) and focus on arguments 4 (before skip) & 5 (after skip).

Here's an example that adjust the space before and after the `\subparagraph` unit:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering\normalfont\normalsize}
\subsectionfont{\noindent\normalfont\normalsize\emph}
%\subsubsectionfont{\indent\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}
\subparagraphfont{\indent\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Some text
\subsection{A subsection}
Some text
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
Some text
\paragraph{A paragraph}
Some text
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}
Some text

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
      {2\baselineskip \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
      {\baselineskip}%
%     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@subparafont}}
\makeatother

\subparagraph{A subparagraph}
Some text

\end{document}
```

Note that `sectsty` is assuming that your working with a document class for which the sectional units use `\@startsection` without modification from the default classes, with the exclusion of [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) (from the [`sectsty` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty/sectsty.pdf); section **1 Introduction**, p 2):

> The `secsty` package provides a set of commands for changing the font
>   used for the various sectional headings in the standard LaTeX 2e document
>   classes: `article`, `book`, and `report`. This package also works with the
>   KOMA-Script classes `scrartcl`, `scrbook`, and `scrreprt`.

While it "will work" with other document classes, the effect is merely to overwrite the sectional units' definitions with that of the default document classes mentioned above. For example, [`apa6`](http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6) defines

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {\b@level@one@skip}{\e@level@one@skip}%
    {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {\b@level@two@skip}{\e@level@two@skip}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\newcommand*{\addperi}[1]{#1.}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\parindent}%
    {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\addperi}}

\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\parindent}%
    {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape\addperi}}

\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{1em}%
    {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
    {-\z@\relax}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape\hspace{\parindent}{#1}\textit{.}}{\relax}}
```

In order to maintain the sectional unit structure, you're better off redefining the above set manually<sup>*</sup> (separate from `sectsty`, as was done in the first example). The same approach would hold (including a redefinition to your liking within a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) pair) as `apa6` also uses `\@startsection` to define the sectional units.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Of course, other packages could be used as well, if they are compatible with `apa6`, but that seems to be out of the question here.</sub>

Comment: Since you have to redefine `\subparagragraph` anyway, what's the point in using `sectsty`?

Comment: @egreg: The OP wants to update the `\subparagraph` *spacing*, but maintain some consistency/ease in terms of the modification for all other sectional unit *fonts*. Either way, [`apa6`](http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6) (the document class in use) is "not compatible" with [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty), so I've added some more detail.

Comment: @Werner, "apa6 is not compatible with sectsty". Good to know, I wish we didn't use `sectsty` to start with, it's being a pain so far.