# how to reduce horizontal space before and after paragraph/subparagraph/sectional headings

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{Subsubection}
\lipsum[3]
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[4]
\subparagraph{Subparagraph}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

However, there is a lot of horizontal space before and after each Section/paragraph headings. the subparagraph also has an unnecessary indentation.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168340/adjusting-spacing-before-and-after-subparagraph-with-sectsty?rq=1

Comment: Is it possible to avoid sectsty

Comment: I was able to get it all working using titleformat and titlespacing.

Comment: @user3236841 I posted my answer and then just seen your comment, glad you got it sorted, I needed that for an article template too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Included both horizontal spaces (after heading number) and spacing before and after titles without using `sectsty`. Change the formatting commands in \titleformat as required and the horizontal spacing between the number and heading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % EDIT - allows multiple font styles %

% Change horizontal space in titles here
% [block]{Formatting command}{Put `the' in front of paragraph etc}{Space after number}{}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.2em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large\scshape}{\thesubsection}{0.3em}{}

% EDIT - to show the multiple font styles being applied due to package `fontenc`
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[block]{\scshape\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{0.3em}{}

% Change vertical space \beforetitle and \aftertitle here, as above use \subparagraph etc.
% 0pt is how far from the left margin the entry is placed

\newcommand\aftertitle{2ex}
\newcommand\beforetitle{0.7ex}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\aftertitle}{\beforetitle}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{\aftertitle}{\beforetitle}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\aftertitle}{\beforetitle}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{\aftertitle}{\beforetitle}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0pt}{\aftertitle}{\beforetitle}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{Subsubection}
\lipsum[3]
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[4]
\subparagraph{Subparagraph}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

How it looks (EDIT - updated to include `fontenc` package for subparagraph formatting):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to change the subparagraph to small caps in boldface so that they look different?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I'm probably in a different time zone. To have multiple fonts, you need to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble and then use `\titleformat{\subparagraph}[block]{\large\scshape\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{0.3em}{}` where 0.3em is the horizontal space of your choosing. The `fontenc` package prevents the final font style from overriding the previous ones.

Comment: I've edited my answer so the MWE should do as you require, hope it helps.

Comment: thanks! i see, fontenc is needed. I wish I could rate this answer up one more time!