# \newcommand for centered \section

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am trying to use the `titlesec` package to achieve this but I'm not certain as to what the syntax should be...

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\centeredsection}{\titleformat{\section}{\centering}}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So did it work? Also, please post **complete** code. Questions should always include a Minimal Working Example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all section titles centered, it suffices to use the starred form of `\titleformat` in this way:

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
Some text

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Instead, if you are trying to create a new sectioning command which have a centered title, this can not be done in this way (supposing you are using the `article` class):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\centeredsection{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\centeredsection{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\centeredsection{Centered section}
Some text

\section{Normal section}
Some text

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Karl. This works great. May I ask what `{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%` does exactly? I read the following link, but still dont quite understand it.http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31780/where-can-i-find-help-files-or-documentation-for-commands-like-startsection-fo

Comment: @Giri You're welcome. I've simply taken the definition of `\section` and added `\centering`. `{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}` is the spacing before the section title (`-3.5ex` is the real spacing while `\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex` is the glue). The latter one is the spacing after the section title (with similar meanings).

Answer (score 7):

This is how it is done with `titlesec`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,showframe}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\filcenter\Large
\normalfont\bfseries}
{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{5pc}{*2}{*2}[5pc]

\begin{document}

\section{test}
Some text


\end{document}
```

[image]

With `sectsty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty,showframe}

\sectionfont{\centering}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
Some text


\end{document}
```

If you want to define a new section command that is centered, this is not the way. But following is an example of doing it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
%%make \section centered
\patchcmd{\section}{\normalfont}{\centering\normalfont}{}{}
%% assign \section to \centeredsection
\LetLtxMacro{\centeredsection}{\section}
%% revert \centering from regular section
\patchcmd{\section}{\centering\normalfont}{\normalfont}{}{}


\begin{document}
\centeredsection{Centered section}
Some text

\section{Normal section}
Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Harish. I inserted what you had for `titlesec` after `\newcommand{\centeredsection}` in my code but it seemed to center my other headings and not my `\newcommand` `centeredsection`...

Comment: Your solution causes the first paragraph after the `\section` command to be indented, whereas "normal LaTeX" behavior is not to insert `\parindent` at the start of the first paragraph following a sectioning command. Is there a way to remedy this situation?

Comment: @Mico Just to use `\titlespacing*{\section}
{5pc}{*2}{*2}[5pc]` is the remedy.

Comment: @Giri I have updated the answer.