# Small editing issues in LyX document

Tags: lyx

I'm editing a LyX document and am struggling with a few issues:

1. I would like to include an abstract but suppresses the word "Abstract" above the abstract.
2. The title sections and "References" are in in default in bold. I can manually change the section titles to not bold, but not the section numbers. Do you know how to unbold these?
3. I would like to change "References" (in bold) to "REFERENCES" not in bold.
4. Titles and "References" are by default on the left; I would like to have them centered.

Thank you very much in advanced for enlightening me!

Tompv

Comment: Which document class are you using? *Article (AMS)* has some of this by default.

Comment: Thanks Torbjørn T. I was just using the standard one and, indeed, (AMS) does solve some of the issues. But it creates others at the same time (such as putting the title on the top of each page, number the equations differently, etc.). Would you recommend me to start from that one nonetheless?

Comment: No, not necessarily, just thought I'd mention it. I'll add an answer in a bit. (For the future, it's best if you limit questions to a single issue. Questions should generally be quite specific.)

Comment: This sounds a lot like APA formatting; is there some style you're trying to adhere to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1 and 3

In a way, questions 1 and 3 are the same, or they can at least be answered in the same way, which is that described in [Translate paragraph environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119117/translate-paragraph-environment).

In short, if you're using `babel`, which I think is the default behaviour, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and add

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addto\captionsenglish{%
    \renewcommand\abstractname{}
    \renewcommand\refname{REFERENCES}
}}
```

If `babel` is turned off, you need just

```
\renewcommand\abstractname{}
\renewcommand\refname{REFERENCES}
```

In either case only the PDF will change, not the view in LyX.

(For the abstract, another way would be to 'cheat' a bit by using Quote instead of Abstract, and reducing the font size to Small.)

### 2 and 4

Question 2 and 4 are also sort of the same question, they are about formatting `\section`s. In `article` (which is the default document class used by LyX), the References-heading is an unnumbered section, so the same formatting applies.

The LaTeX answer can be found in the first part of the answer to [\newcommand for centered \section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168472/newcommand-for-centered-section), you just need to remove the `\bfseries`, as you didn't want them to be bold. To apply this in LyX, again go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\normalfont\Large}
```

[image]