# How to reduce space before \paragraph

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I am using `\documentclass[11pt]{article}` and I would like to reduce the space very slightly that is put in before each `\paragraph{Some text}`.

A MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
Hello
\paragraph{A paragraph}
Some more text

And we continue.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\paragraph` is the 4th level section heading, it's wrong to use that without `\section` ... `\subsubsection`  but assuming this is just an example, copy the definition of `\paragraph` from `article.cls` into your preamble and reduce the lengths

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I am actually using \paragraph within sections. Is there a better way to get inline bold titles?

Comment: if it is part of your section hierarchy it is more correct to use `\subsection` defined using `\@startsection` in werner's answer but with `{2}` instead of `{4}` or if it's a kind of ad hoc heading not really part of the hierarchy you could just use `\textbf{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to adjust the fourth argument supplied to `\@startsection` as part of [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls)'s definition of `\paragraph`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
Hello
\paragraph{A paragraph}
Some more text

And we continue.

\bigskip
\hrulefill
\bigskip

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                      {\parskip}%{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                      {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

Hello
\paragraph{A paragraph}
Some more text

And we continue.

\end{document}
```

My reference of reducing the space before "very slightly" was to take it down from `3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex` to `\parskip` (`0pt \@plus 1pt`).

As a reference, see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764).