# Reducing chapter and section spacing for scrbook

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, koma-script, sections-paragraphs

I'm using `scrbook` document class and using chapters and sections. The spacing between chapters and sections is quite large, too large for my taste (before and after the chapter and section). So my question is how can this spacing be reduced? (saw a few variants for non-KOMA document classes but those don't seem to work for this class).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof,parskip=full]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}            
\usepackage{multicol}      

\twocolumn
\raggedright
\Chapter{chap1}
\Section{sec1}
blaahblah
\Section{sec2}
Blah
\Chapter{chap2}
BlahBlah
\Chapter{chap3}
Blah
```

Edit:
After applying the changes that Werner mentioned I have the following phenomenon (the code excerpts and the screenshot are to show what I tried to describe in the comments):

"Species" is a chapter, "Applying" is a section, Advantages and Disadvantages are subsections each.

Code excerpt for the disadvantages (1 enter is before and after the subsection):

```
all perception rolls.

\subsection{Disadvantages}

\noindent\textbf{Bestial psychology and territorial instincts}: Dragons despite their intellect are part beast. This means that they have strong territo
```

Code excerpt for the chapter part:

```
\chapter{Species template}

\section{Applying the template}

\subsection{Advantages}

\noindent\textbf{Dragons bodies}: +5.....
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `scrbook`/`scrreport`, the skip before/at the end of a chapter is given by

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{%
  \vspace*{2.3\baselineskip}%
}%
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
  \vspace{1.725\baselineskip
    \@plus .115\baselineskip \@minus .192\baselineskip}%
}%
```

Adjust them to your liking. In terms of `\section`s, the [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle still uses `\@startsection` (see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764)). Here's the definition for `\section`:

```
\newcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{\sectionnumdepth}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
```

Adjust the two rubber lengths (arguments `#4` and `#5` to `\@startsection`) to suit your needs.

Here is a minimal example where the mentioned lengths have been adjusted:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof,parskip=full,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{0pt}}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\section}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-\baselineskip}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{.5\baselineskip}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\raggedright
\chapter{chap1}
\section{sec1}
blaahblah
\section{sec2}
Blah
\chapter{chap2}
BlahBlah
\chapter{chap3}
Blah

\end{document}
```

Of course the above only references changes to `\chapter` and `\section`. You'd have to adjust lower-level sectional units in an analogous way. For example, here's an option to remove even more spacing around the sectional units, this time including that of `\subsection`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{0pt}}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\section}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-\z@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{1sp}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-\z@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{1sp}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@xsect}{\ignorespaces}{\vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}\ignorespaces}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I tried around a bit now. The chapter is clear so far, but for section and subsection I'm not 100% getting it how to modify it so that it is only half a normal line before and after it

Comment: @ThomasE.: Try the following three patches: `\patchcmd{\section}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-\z@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{1sp}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@xsect}{\ignorespaces}{\vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}\ignorespaces}{}{}`.

Comment: taht works for chapter (2x enter), section(2x enter), subsection(2x enter) being under each other nicely. strangely if I put a \noindent\textbf, 2x enter, \subsection{Disadvantages}, 2x enter it still has the same distance as before

Comment: do you have any idea there @Werner?

Comment: @ThomasE.: Could you update your question with an edit showing the current problem?

Comment: I edited a screenshot into it and also put up the codeparts of teh parts shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @ThomasE.: Ahhh, I see that you're using `\subsection`s, yet I've only patched `\section`. I've added the necessary changes to my answer.

Comment: Yepp that helped a lot tnx.