# Page break problem after \subsection in LNCS format

Tags: page-breaking

I am using `LNCS` template to author a paper. But, weirdly at random point, if I add a `\subsection` a page break appears between 'Abstract' and 'First Section':

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{url}
%\urldef{\mailsa}\path|{alfred.hofmann, ursula.barth, ingrid.haas, frank.holzwarth,|
%\urldef{\mailsb}\path|anna.kramer, leonie.kunz, christine.reiss, nicole.sator,|
%\urldef{\mailsc}\path|erika.siebert-cole, peter.strasser, lncs}@springer.com|    
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\addvspace\baselineskip
\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter  % start of an individual contribution

% first the title is needed
\title{XXXXXX}
% a short form should be given in case it is too long for the running head
%\titlerunning{Lecture Notes in Computer Science: Authors' Instructions}

% the name(s) of the author(s) follow(s) next
%
% NB: Chinese authors should write their first names(s) in front of
% their surnames. This ensures that the names appear correctly in
% the running heads and the author index.
%
\author{}
%\author{Alfred Hofmann%
%\thanks{Please note that the LNCS Editorial assumes that all authors have used
%the western naming convention, with given names preceding surnames. This determines
%the structure of the names in the running heads and the author index.}%
%\and Ursula Barth\and Ingrid Haas\and Frank Holzwarth\and\\
%Anna Kramer\and Leonie Kunz\and Christine Rei\ss\and\\
%Nicole Sator\and Erika Siebert-Cole\and Peter Stra\ss er}
%
%\authorrunning{Lecture Notes in Computer Science: Authors' Instructions}
% (feature abused for this document to repeat the title also on left hand pages)

% the affiliations are given next; don't give your e-mail address
% unless you accept that it will be published
\institute{}
%\institute{Springer-Verlag, Computer Science Editorial,\\
%Tiergartenstr. 17, 69121 Heidelberg, Germany\\
%\mailsa\\
%\mailsb\\
%\mailsc\\
%\url{http://www.springer.com/lncs}}

%
% NB: a more complex sample for affiliations and the mapping to the
% corresponding authors can be found in the file "llncs.dem"
% (search for the string "\mainmatter" where a contribution starts).
% "llncs.dem" accompanies the document class "llncs.cls".
%

%\toctitle{Lecture Notes in Computer Science}
%\tocauthor{Authors' Instructions}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
Dummy abstract
\keywords{}
\end{abstract}


\section{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\section{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\section{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\section{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\subsection{XXXXXX}

\section{XXXXXX}

%\subsection{XXXXXX}% Uncomment this to see the problem

\end{document}
```

What surprising is, I am adding a `\subsection` at the end and the break appears at the very beginning, after the first page. Can anyone please give me any clue on how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Your minimal example isn't really reflective of a typical document, but the output is as expected. Here's why...

Each of the sectional units go through the same macro during construction, `\@startsection`. [This macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764) conditions on whether the sectional heading is supposed to be "run-in" or "display". In a display section, the title is set on a single line with the paragraph content following on a separate line. However, to avoid dangling sectional headings at the bottom of a page, a `\nobreak` is issued. This allows the sectional heading to be joined/glued (not separated) with the succeeding paragraph (well, not *all* of it), either keeping them both on the current page, or flushing both to the following page.

In your setup, you've *only* used sectional units to build your document (`\section`s and `\subsection`s). Both these sectional headings are set as a display and therefore force a `\nobreak`. With all the headings issuing `\nobreak`s, they're virtually "stuck together". Once there's a page break to issue, the entire block of sectional units can *only* be flushed to a following page, since the abstract is the only piece of text where a reliable page break can be inserted.

This is just a special scenario and it shouldn't be of concern in a regular (real) document that also contains paragraph text.

Comment: After writing something, the problem got solved!