# Understand spacing of “named paragraphs”

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

*It was tricky to find related questions given the specific wording. I hope I'm not making a duplicate, and I apologise if it is the case.*

## Question

In my `\subsubsection` I have 3 “named paragraphs” *A*, *B* and *C*. Each “named paragraph” introduces a wide space before them. I would like to keep writing my subsection, after *C*, but no separation space is inserted. What am I doing wrong?

```
\subsubsection{Title}
Bla bla bla.

\paragraph{A.} Bla bla bla.
\paragraph{B.} Bla bla bla.
\paragraph{C.} Bla bla bla.

Bla bla bla.
```

[image: Paragraphs]

## Answer

Correct usage of “named paragraph” is done with the `description` environment from `enumitem` package, as pointed out by [**@Gustavo Mezzetti**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/69818/gustavo-mezzetti) and illustrated by [**@Werner**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner).

```
\subsubsection{Title}
Bla bla bla.

\begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]
  \item[A.] Bla bla bla.
  \item[B.] Bla bla bla.
  \item[C.] Bla bla bla.
\end{description}

Bla bla bla.
```

[image: Description]

**Note:** one needs to include `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the preamble.

Comment: That's expected: the name `\paragraph` was an unfortunate choice; it is a sectioning command just like `\section`, `\subsection`.and `\subsubsection`, ranking after the last one. In the `article` class it is realized with an in-line title. Since it starts a sectional unit, it can consist of several paragraphs.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are asking for, you could use, for example, a `description` environment.

Comment: That's it, @Gustavo. I was after `description`, and I thought it was `paragraph` instead. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being confused by the command's name: `\paragraph` is actually one of the standard sectioning command hierarchy:

```
\part
\chapter
\section
\subsection
\subsubsection
\paragraph
\subparagraph
```

These commands are defined in the standard classes (but `article` doesn't have `\chapter`) and most other classes follow the same convention.

It's rather common opinion that the names for the last two commands was badly chosen, but it's too late for changing them, as they've been in LaTeX for thirty years.

The usual difference between `\(sub)paragraph` and `\(sub)(sub)section` is that the latter type prints the title as a block, whereas the former type print the title in-line.

Being a sectional command, it doesn't act on a single (text) paragraph, but just marks a division in the document. Hence it does nothing special at the end of the (text) paragraph it's in.

You could abuse `\paragraph` by making your own environment; the spacing below is the same as the space above in the `article` class and with other classes it might be necessary to change it; defining an environment will enable doing the modification very easily.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{namedparagraph}[1]
  {\paragraph{#1}}
  {\par\addvspace{3.25ex plus 1ex minus 0.2ex}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Title}
Bla bla bla.

\begin{namedparagraph}{A.}
Bla bla bla.
\end{namedparagraph}

\begin{namedparagraph}{B.}
Bla bla bla.
\end{namedparagraph}

\begin{namedparagraph}{C.}
Bla bla bla.
\end{namedparagraph}

Bla bla bla.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you are probably looking for the `description` environment, maybe tailored to your needs with the help of `enumitem`.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I was after `description`. Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the same amount of space by looking at the definition of `\paragraph` in `article.cls`:

```
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

The *fourth* argument passed to `\@startsection` defines the space inserted above the `\paragraph` unit, or the **beforeskip** - `3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex` - see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764). It's a flexible (or rubber) length, but you can insert that manually as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Title}
Bla bla bla.

\paragraph{A.} \lipsum[1]
\paragraph{B.} \lipsum[2]
\paragraph{C.} \lipsum[3]

\vspace{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}% Space above a typical \paragraph

\noindent
Bla bla bla.

\end{document}
```

The reason why there's no gap between your `\paragraph{C.}` and the subsequent `Bla bla bla` is because that distance is governed by `\parskip` which is 0pt (actually `0.0pt plus 0.1pt`) under the default `article` class.

There are other ways of achieving your goal, like using a list like `description`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Title}
Bla bla bla.

\begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]
  \item[A.] \lipsum[1]
  \item[B.] \lipsum[2]
  \item[C.] \lipsum[3]
\end{description}

\noindent
Bla bla bla.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, perhaps also `\addpenalty{\@secpenalty}`, in this case?

Comment: If I am permitted to add another suggestion, I would also recommend using `\addvspace` rather than `\vspace`, here.

Comment: Thank you for posting a workaround. But I was more into understanding how to properly use the tools that LaTeX offers. It looks like I'll have to delve into the `description` environment, as suggested by @Gustavo.

Comment: @Atcold: Then consider *not* asking "What am I doing wrong?" Be specific in your request. I've added a list-like option using `description`.

Comment: Well, one of the comments above mentioned that the name `\paragraph` was an unfortunate choice and it is a sectioning command just like `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`, ranking after the last one. In the `article` class it is realized with an in-line title. Hence, it addresses my question, i.e. the usage is not relative to a single paragraph but it's a sectioning element. And I understand I can add extra space, although this does not explain why the space was not the in first place.

Comment: From the title I'm referring to 'named paragraphs' because that's how they look in the `article` class. I would have been more precise if I knew what I was doing, but I was not. Therefor, the answer is, "named paragraphs are realised with the `description` environment and not with the `\paragraph` command". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Using the `[leftmargin=0pt]` I get a `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` `leading text:   \item[A.]`. Without it, it works, but indentation is still there. I'm puzzled... Oops, ok `\usepackage{enumitem}` is required. I thought it was standard LaTeX.

Comment: @Atcold: Strange that you accepted an answer that doesn't use a list, yet you placed that as the **Answer** in you post.

Comment: The **Answer** points out my misunderstanding, which addresses the question "What am I doing wrong?". I've included a more targeted answer (with your working example) in my question. There was no need to down-vote my question, though.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Gustavo Mezzeti's suggestion, you might use this:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
. . . . . .
\begin{document}
. . . . . .
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*, wide=0pt, font=\bfseries]
\item Blah blah blah 
\item Booh booh booh
\item Fiddle dee dee!
\end{enumerate}
. . . . . .
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right, probably the OP doesn’t want descriptive titles, but just alphabetic labels.

Comment: My bad, OP wants descriptive titles. My apologies.