# How to add header for subsubsection in LNCS format?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, line-breaking, lncs

LNCS format has a run in style for subsubsection. I followed some instructions to modify the class file for LNCS, then there are newlines after each subsubsection, however, the header is missing. How to make the subsubsection looks like this:

```
1.1.1 example
example, example, example
```

now it lookes like this

```
example
example, example, example
```

The modified class file:

```
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                       {-18\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {4\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath
                        \rightskip=\z@ \@plus 8em\pretolerance=10000 }}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                       {-12\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {2\p@ \@plus 1\p@ \@minus 1\p@}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape
                        \rightskip=\z@ \@plus 8em\pretolerance=10000 }}
```

Besides, I'm using `lncs.cls`, a working example should look like this:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\title{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}

\author{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\institute{ xxxx \\ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\maketitle

\begin{xx}
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{xx}

\section{xxxx}~\label{xxxx}

xxxxxx

\subsection{xxxx}\label{xxx}

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\subsubsection{xxxx}

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


\bibliography{kk}
\bibliographystyle{splncs}
\end{document}
```

where subsubsection doesn't have a head like this:

```
1.1.1 example subsubsection
```

instead, the numbers are missing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that is sufficient to update the display of `\subsubsection` to

1. have enumeration; and
2. is formatted as a *display* (with a line-break after the title).

For the first requirement, add

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}% Number up to \subsubsection
```

to your preamble. `\subsubsection`s are "level `3`" sectional units. The default setting under [`llncs`](https://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) is to have the `secnumdepth` counter set to `2`, numbering only up to `\subsection`.

For the second requirement you need to understand what the arguments of `\@startsection` does. Read up on this at [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764) The `<afterskip>` length - argument `#5` - should be positive rather than negative. Here is the default definition within `llncs.cls` for `\subsubsection`:

```
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                       {-18\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {-0.5em \@plus -0.22em \@minus -0.1em}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}
```

We can change this to

```
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                       {-18\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {0.5em \@plus 0.22em \@minus 0.1em}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}
```

(or something similar).

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                       {-18\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {0.5em \@plus 0.22em \@minus 0.1em}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
This is part of a section.

\subsection{A subsection}
This is part of a subsection.

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
This is part of a subsubsection.

\end{document}
```