# Reduce the spacing between paragraphs

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

The problem I have is that the spacing between the paragraphs are too large. I have tried the `\setlength{\parskip}{0.1mm}` command but it does not give the correct spacing that I want.

I have also tried `\raggedbottom` but neither does that work.

Here is some example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.1mm}
\raggedbottom

\title{Open Source och Licenser}
\author{Martin}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\paragraph{}
\blindtext
\paragraph{}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I read in another thread that the `parskip` package would be good to use for this kind of problem, but I did not get it to work. As you can see I have commented the `\usepackage{parskip}` because all it does in my document is reducing the spacing between the title and the author lines.

Here is an image of how the document looks:

[image]

What I want to do is to reduce the spacing between the paragraphs so it is almost non existent. Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: That's easy, just drop the use of `\paragraph{}`...

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: @martin36: Obviously you are confusing `\paragraph` with paragraph -- the paragraph ;-)

Comment: @Werner If I comment the `\paragraph{}` then the text just becomes one large paragraph. I still want the spacing in between but just a smaller one.

Comment: @martin36: Leave a blank line, or use an explicit `\par`. The former is more readily used than explicitly typing `\par`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\paragraph{}` doesn't have to be issued to start a paragraph. It is actually a sectional unit (level 4, in fact) used to set a *heading* for a paragraph (usually run-in). Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{First paragraph}
\blindtext
\paragraph{Second paragraph}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Since `\paragraph` sets a *heading* it also adds some space before it to separate it from the regular paragraph text. Without it, leave a blank line or insert an explicit `\par` to separate a paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The result `\par` gave me was more what I was looking for. But do you know if there is a way to reduce the spacing between paragraphs using `\paragraph`?

Comment: @martin36: Since `\paragraph` is a sectional heading setting, by default is uses `\@startsection` (search for `\paragraph` in [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co)). And `\@startsection` has one of its argument dedicated to the space *before* setting the heading. See **beforeskip** in [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31795/5764) So, you can redefine `\paragraph` to use a different **beforeskip** or use a package (like `titlesec`, say).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check that out, but it seems pretty difficult to do for my skill level.

Comment: @martin36 you should not need to check it out at any skill level as using `\paragraph{}` is incorrect markup it is a heading with no heading so there should not be a need to customize it. Also using `\par` is unnecessary it is just the same as leaving a blank line.

Comment: @martin36: Using the default `\@startsection` is not necessary, if you're using a package. However, you could try adding `\makeatletter \renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}} \makeatother` to your preamble and change the value of `3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus.2ex` to (say) `1mm`. Then see what that does to your output. However, for just plain paragraphs, *don't* use `\paragraph`.

Comment: @Werner I tried what you wrote and changed `3.25ex` to `1mm` and it gives a perfect space between the paragraphs. But I will remember not to use the `\paragraph{}` for separation plain paragraphs in the future.