# Paragraph Indent in Section Heading

Tags: sectioning, indentation

My university requires an indent for sections and subsections headings like on the picture.
[image: example]

How can I do it?

Comment: This does really look awful.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sure, but it is a university's requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all my sympathy: university requirements are so silly, sometimes!

If your sections and subsections are always numbered, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\hspace*{\parindent}\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text to show the indentation in the first line
Some text to show the indentation in the first line
Some text to show the indentation in the first line

\section{Test}

\subsection{Test}

Some text to show the indentation in the first line
Some text to show the indentation in the first line
Some text to show the indentation in the first line

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've helped so much! I've spent several hours in Google trying to find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Please try with the below code:

```
 \newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{12\p@}%
                                   {-12\p@}%
                                   {6\p@}
{\normalsize\raggedright}}
```

Comment: Where is this mysterious code coming from?

Comment: @Johannes_B If you think of the `\startsection` macro you may have a look at this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31780/where-can-i-find-help-files-or-documentation-for-commands-like-startsection-fo

Comment: @jürgen i am wondering about asecdimen.

Comment: Oops..its my own tag, it should be as in value, ie., 6\p@ etc. thanks for point out this...

Comment: @Jürgen: I am pretty sure that Johannes_B is aware of `\@startsection` ;-)

Comment: Yes, so I was quite surprised. ;-)  I simply overlooked the `\asecdimen` and `\bsecdimen`.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I would propose to edit your answer accordingly to your own comment.