# How to adjust the title spacing using sectsty package

Tags: spacing, sectioning, sectsty

I'm writing a paper with some specifications in the section titles. I know that `titlesec` package is an excellent alternatve, but becuse some compatibility problems I have to use `sectsty`. I don't know how to specify the space before and after the section and subsection titles with this package. I saw the package documentation and some answers here, but I didn't find anything.

Some hints?

Comment: As Werner points out in his answer, what you want to do is not possible with `sectsty`. The package is meant for changing the font only. It is a bit like asking how to get a nail into the wall with toilet paper. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine the entire `\section` (and other commands) to suit your needs. Here are the defaults from [`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty):

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
      {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\SS@sectfont}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
      {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
      {\normalfont\large\bfseries\SS@subsectfont}}
```

Since `sectsty` only changes the font, the only difference between the above and the default definition from the base document class is the addition of `\SS@<sec>font` to each sectional unit.

Referring to [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764), you should change arguments `#4` (`<beforeskip>`) and `#5` (`<afterskip>`). Here is one option you can add to your preamble that increases the `<beforeskip>` and `<afterskip>` slightly:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
      {-5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% <beforeskip>
      {3ex \@plus.2ex}% <afterskip>
      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\SS@sectfont}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
      {-4ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% <beforeskip>
      {2ex \@plus .2ex}% <afterskip>
      {\normalfont\large\bfseries\SS@subsectfont}}
\makeatother
```