# Linebreak After Subsubsection Title in IEEEtran

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, ieeetran

I'm using the IEEEtran document class and want my subsubsection to have arabic numbering and a linebreak between the subsubsection title and the subsubsection body. I've achieved the arabic numbering with the following code.

```
\def\thesubsubsectiondis{\thesubsectiondis\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

However, no matter what I do I cannot get a linebreak between the title and body.  Can anyone tell me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764), here is the definition of `\subsubsection` within [`IEEEtran.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls):

```
\def\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection
    {subsubsection}                 % name
    {3}                             % level
    {\parindent}                    % indent
    {0ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}    % beforeskip
    {0ex}                           % afterskip
    {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}% style
}%
```

Note that the **afterskip** length is `0ex` (not positive):

> **afterskip**: If positive, then skip to leave below heading, else negative of skip to leave to right of run-in heading.

As such, `\subsubsection` will be set as a run-in heading. That is, no following line/paragraph break. If you want this, use some length that is positive. Here's an example that matches the definition of `\subsection`'s **afterskip**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\def\thesubsubsectiondis{\thesubsectiondis\arabic{subsubsection}}

\makeatletter
\def\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection
    {subsubsection}                 % type
    {3}                             % level
    {\parindent}                    % indent
    {3.5ex plus 1.5ex minus 1.5ex}  % beforeskip {0ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}
    {0.7ex plus .5ex minus 0ex}     % afterskip {0ex}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}% style
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Lorem ipsum \ldots

\subsection{A subsection}
Lorem ipsum \ldots

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
Lorem ipsum \ldots

\end{document}
```

You'll see that I also changed the **beforeskip** to that of `\subsection`. Using the default seemed strange.

Comment: This is the most clean, clear, and sufficiently detailed explanation of section command definition that I have ever seen. I've been unable to grasp any of the related documentation for quite a while, but this finally sheds some light on it, especially the link to the \@startsection explanation. It's especially helpful that you broke out each part of the command definition on a separate line with a commented description of what each part does. Thank you!