# How do I read the LaTeX kernel code source?

Tags: latex-base

I'm embarrassed to ask this. At one time I knew the answer and even had a printed copy of the code. I have tried `texdoc` with various options but was unable to come up with the one I needed.

At the moment I am particularly interested in the definitions of `\addcontentsline`, `\contentsline`, `\addtocontents` and any friends.

GOM

Comment: Perhaps [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764) (points to [`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) and/or [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)).

Comment: You can do `kpsewhich latex.ltx` in the terminal/command prompt and open the file it returns. If you do `kpsewhich -a latex.ltx` it will also show you the path to the `-dev` version. In my distribution they are in `$TEXMF/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx` and `$TEXMF/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/latex.ltx`, respectively.

Comment: `texdoc source2e`

Answer (score 6):

```
texdoc source2e
```

However, this has a problem right now as I just noticed: what you get are the sources for the prerelease for 2020-02-02.

The current one you need to use

```
texdoc -l source2e
```

and then select `2`.

Or go to:

http://latex-project.org/help/documentation/

where you find the sources as pdf as well as several other documents.