# Scrutinise dtx source on fundamental latex environments

Tags: environments

I would like to scrutinise the documented source (.dtx) for the implementation on fundamental latex environments.

For instance,

`\begin{document}`, `\begin{itemize}`, `\begin{table}`,
`\begin{equation}`, `\begin{figure}`, `\begin{quote}`.

Comment: `texdoc source2e`, but there's a lot of stuff there: not sure that's really an answer (and if it is, I'm thinking it's a dupe)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31780/where-can-i-find-help-files-or-documentation-for-commands-like-startsection-fo and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517646/how-do-i-read-the-latex-kernel-code-source/517662#517662 look like potential candidates

Comment: I want to look directly at the actual dtx files for a number of fundamental environments.  And for some of those mentioned in the list I have provided.

Comment: Well `source2e` is the `.dtx` files, just typeset; you can work out from `latex.ltx` which `.dtx` you want and open it (I do that, but then I'm often wanting to edit the source - pretty unusual). I am wondering what you hope to learn: you won't find `\begin{document}` for example, rather `\begin` and `\document`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151719/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-ragonese).