# Add an asterisk left of an enumerate

Tags: lists, enumitem

I am looking for a simple way of adding an asterisk or some small image to the left of an enumerate such that the indentation of the enumeration is not affected by the latter. I have read [Add asterisk after labels in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21004/10898) and [Add an asterisk in front of section label in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16341/10898) in which the latter has the effect am looking for.

> Update: egreg's solution below is nice and does answer the problem. But I want the possible `newcommand` to be used without introducing an `newenvironment` like just having `\moditem` inside the enumerate and working with `enumitem`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just modify accordingly the `modenumerate` environment defined in [Add asterisk after labels in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21004/10898)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newenvironment{modenumerate}
  {\enumerate\setupmodenumerate}
  {\endenumerate}

\newif\ifmoditem
\newcommand{\setupmodenumerate}{%
  \global\moditemfalse
  \let\origmakelabel\makelabel
  \def\moditem##1{\global\moditemtrue\def\mesymbol{##1}\item}%
  \def\makelabel##1{%
    \origmakelabel{\ifmoditem\llap{\mesymbol\enspace}\fi##1}%
    \global\moditemfalse}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{modenumerate}
\item uno
\item due
\moditem{*} tre
\item quattro
\end{modenumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\item uno
\item due
\item tre
\item quattro
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Instead of `*` you can use anything you want, as long as it can be set into an `\mbox`. The following `enumerate` is just to show that the result is the same.

---

If you are using the `enumitem` package, the following code allows the use of `\moditem` in any `enumerate` environment:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{before=\setupmodenumerate}

\newif\ifmoditem
\newcommand{\setupmodenumerate}{%
  \global\moditemfalse
  \let\origmakelabel\makelabel
  \def\moditem##1{\global\moditemtrue\def\mesymbol{##1}\item}%
  \def\makelabel##1{%
    \origmakelabel{\ifmoditem\llap{\mesymbol\enspace}\fi##1}%
    \global\moditemfalse}%
}
```

If you don't use `enumitem`, then change the first two lines into

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\enumerate}{\setupmodenumerate}
```

Comment: I guess it was that hard to figure that one out...:-) Guess its just my lack of understanding your the code above. Is there another way without introducing a new enumerate environment? Like just having `\moditem` within the normal enumerate.

Comment: @azetina You can try `\appto{\enumerate}{\setupmodenumerate}` (requires the `etoolbox` package), but it won't work with `enumitem`

Comment: No way of doing it with enumitem, right?

Comment: @azetina You could try `\setlist[enumerate]{before=\setupmodenumerate}`

Comment: Congrats on your 100k record. :-)