# Adding an asterisk to specific numbering in the multienum package

Tags: macros, lists

@egreg answered beautifully my question on [adding an asterisk to an item locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61263/579) by introducing the command `\moditem`. I am wondering if this is possible with specific items in the `multienum` package. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{multienum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multienumerate}
    {\renewcommand{\labelname}{\llap{*}\csname
labelenum\romannumeral\themultienumdepth\endcsname}
        \mitemx{one}
        \mitemxx{two}{three}}
        \mitemxx{four}{five}
    \end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem I see is that the `multienum` does not define each item independently, e.g. `\mitemxx{<content>}{<content>}`. So for example, if I want to put an asterisk to item 3 it would be a little difficult, at least for me. Essentially, I want to be able to put an asterisk in possibly two different ways:

1. A command like `\mitemax{<content with asterisk>}{<content without asterisk>}` so that wherever the `a` is found then there is where the asterisk is found. So that `\mitemxa` would define a different scenario. Of course, I believe this is tough as you would possibly need to create several custom commands for all scenarios of `\mitemx`, `\mitemxx`, `\mitemxxx`, `\mitemxxxx`,`\mitemxxxxx`.
2. Simply a command, say `\astmitem` that redefines locally the label. For example, `\mitemxx{\astitem <content>}{<content>}` will put an asterisk at the front of the first item. This is easier but I can't figure it out.

### UPDATE

The answer @cgnieder provided was excellent but when I do something like:

```
\newcommand*\doexercise[1][\includegraphics[scale=0.125]{g3016}]{%
  \gdef\labelname{%
    \llap{#1}%
    \csname labelenum\romannumeral\themultienumdepth\endcsname
    \gdef\labelname{%
      \csname labelenum\romannumeral\themultienumdepth\endcsname}%
  }}
```

it does not work. Why? The graphics file could be replaced with any symbol. Works well if you replace `\includegraphics[scale=0.125]{g3016}` with `*`.

---

Solved by replacing `\includegraphics[scale=0.125]{g3016}` with `{\includegraphics[scale=0.125]{g3016}}`. You can read [] inside an optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/5049) for further info as to the fix.

Comment: Have you tried `\newcommand*\doexercise[1][{\includegraphics[scale=0.125]{g3016}}]{...}` (notice the extra pair of braces around `\includegraphics[...`)?

Comment: @cgnieder Why does that work and not as I have it?

Comment: because of the square brackets, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/5049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea for a `\starnext` command that redefines `\labelname` in a way that it will restore itself when called. This gives you nearly the syntax that you outlined in your question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multienum}
\newcommand*\starnext{%
  \gdef\labelname{%
    \llap{*}%
    \csname labelenum\romannumeral\themultienumdepth\endcsname
    \gdef\labelname{%
      \csname labelenum\romannumeral\themultienumdepth\endcsname}%
  }}

\begin{document}

\begin{multienumerate}
  \mitemx{one\starnext}
  \mitemxx{two}{three}
  \mitemxx{four\starnext}{five}
\end{multienumerate}

\begin{multienumerate}\starnext
  \mitemx{one}
  \mitemxx{two}{three\starnext}
  \mitemxx{four}{five}
\end{multienumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to do the job. I had redefined the entire multinenum package but I guess I prefer your code sample. Thanks.

Comment: Can this be done so that the asterisk occurs on the item its placed? I was thinking with an if else statement but hmmmmm not sure.

Comment: @azetina probably not without redefining all the `\mitem<x>` macros

Comment: Why can't I include a graphics. See my question edit.