# List with several types of items

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment

How can one create a list with different types of items ?
I am using the package `enumitem`, which is great for defining items and referring to them, but it seems to allow only one type of item. I have looked in the definition of `\item` in `latex.ltx`, but could not find any useful hint, and in `enumitem.sty` neither.

More concretely I wish to have items like

```
   1 ...
 → 2 ...
 ✓ 3 ...
```

and type

```
\normalitem ...
\arrowitem ...
\checkeditem ...
```

Currently, I use `\item[\refstepcounter{xi}$\symbol$\arabic{thexi}]`
Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: As I am too lazy to  manage complex macros as those of the great answers (+1), just after `\item` I would add macros making something like `\hspace{-2em}\llap{$\rightarrow$}\hspace{2em}`. Simplistic and limited, but simple. `:)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Improved version:

The idea is still the same that I used in the first version (see below), but now the process is completely transparent for the final user; in particular, no extra packages are needed (`pifont` and `tikz` were only loaded in my example to get fancy symbols) and new item types are now defined simply by using

```
\newitem{<prefix>}{<symbol>}
```

where `<prefix>` is the alphabetic string that will be used to call the new item, and `<symbol>` is the symbol that will be pre-pended to the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\myinfo{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node (info) [anchor=base,shape=circle,draw=orange!20,inner sep=1pt,fill=orange,text=white] {\bfseries\sffamily !};%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newitem[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname#1item\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\@inmatherr\csname #1item\endcsname%
    \@ifnextchar[{\csname @#1item\endcsname}{\@noitemargtrue\csname @#1item\endcsname[\@itemlabel]}}%
\expandafter\def\csname @#1item\endcsname[##1]{%
\if@noparitem
\@donoparitem
\else
\if@inlabel
\indent \par
\fi
\ifhmode
\unskip\unskip \par
\fi
\if@newlist
\if@nobreak
\@nbitem
\else
\addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
\addvspace\@topsep
\addvspace{-\parskip}%
\fi
\else
\addpenalty\@itempenalty
\addvspace\itemsep
\fi
\global\@inlabeltrue
\fi
\everypar{%
\@minipagefalse
\global\@newlistfalse
\if@inlabel
\global\@inlabelfalse
{\setbox\z@\lastbox
\ifvoid\z@
\kern-\itemindent
\fi}%
\box\@labels
\penalty\z@
\fi
\if@nobreak
\@nobreakfalse
\clubpenalty \@M
\else
\clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
\everypar{}%
\fi}%
\if@noitemarg
\@noitemargfalse
\if@nmbrlist
\refstepcounter\@listctr
\fi
\fi
\sbox\@tempboxa{\makelabel{#2\kern1pt##1}}%
\global\setbox\@labels\hbox{%
\unhbox\@labels
\hskip \itemindent
\hskip -\labelwidth
\hskip -\labelsep
\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\labelwidth
\box\@tempboxa
\else
\hbox to\labelwidth {\unhbox\@tempboxa}%
\fi
\hskip \labelsep}%
\ignorespaces}
}
\makeatother

\newitem{diamond}{\ding{70}}
\newitem{arrow}{$\to$}
\newitem{checked}{\ding{51}}
\newitem{info}{\myinfo}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\arrowitem First item.
\item Second item.
\checkeditem Third item.
\item Fourth item.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First subitem.
  \arrowitem[($\ast$)] Second subitem.
  \checkeditem Third subitem.
\end{enumerate}
\arrowitem Fifth item.
\item Sixth item.
\infoitem Seventh item.
\checkeditem Eighth item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This solution has an advantage and it is that it can be used on its own (without the `enumitem` package), but it is compatible with the use of this package, if one decides to use it, as the following example demonstrates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\myinfo{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node (info) [anchor=base,shape=circle,draw=orange!20,inner sep=1pt,fill=orange,text=white] {\bfseries\sffamily !};%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newitem[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname#1item\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\@inmatherr\csname #1item\endcsname%
    \@ifnextchar[{\csname @#1item\endcsname}{\@noitemargtrue\csname @#1item\endcsname[\@itemlabel]}}%
\expandafter\def\csname @#1item\endcsname[##1]{%
\if@noparitem
\@donoparitem
\else
\if@inlabel
\indent \par
\fi
\ifhmode
\unskip\unskip \par
\fi
\if@newlist
\if@nobreak
\@nbitem
\else
\addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
\addvspace\@topsep
\addvspace{-\parskip}%
\fi
\else
\addpenalty\@itempenalty
\addvspace\itemsep
\fi
\global\@inlabeltrue
\fi
\everypar{%
\@minipagefalse
\global\@newlistfalse
\if@inlabel
\global\@inlabelfalse
{\setbox\z@\lastbox
\ifvoid\z@
\kern-\itemindent
\fi}%
\box\@labels
\penalty\z@
\fi
\if@nobreak
\@nobreakfalse
\clubpenalty \@M
\else
\clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
\everypar{}%
\fi}%
\if@noitemarg
\@noitemargfalse
\if@nmbrlist
\refstepcounter\@listctr
\fi
\fi
\sbox\@tempboxa{\makelabel{#2\kern1pt##1}}%
\global\setbox\@labels\hbox{%
\unhbox\@labels
\hskip \itemindent
\hskip -\labelwidth
\hskip -\labelsep
\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\labelwidth
\box\@tempboxa
\else
\hbox to\labelwidth {\unhbox\@tempboxa}%
\fi
\hskip \labelsep}%
\ignorespaces}
}
\makeatother

\newitem{diamond}{\ding{70}}
\newitem{arrow}{$\to$}
\newitem{checked}{\ding{51}}
\newitem{info}{\myinfo}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\roman*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\arabic*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\arrowitem First item.
\item Second item.
\checkeditem Third item.
\item Fourth item.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First subitem.
  \arrowitem[($\ast$)] Second subitem.
  \checkeditem Third subitem.
\end{enumerate}
\arrowitem Fifth item.
\item Sixth item.
\infoitem Seventh item.
\checkeditem Eighth item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### The first (preliminary) solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\arrowitem{%
\@inmatherr\arrowitem
\@ifnextchar [\@arrowitem{\@noitemargtrue \@arrowitem[\@itemlabel]}}
\let\@arrowitem\@item
\xpatchcmd{\@arrowitem}
  {\makelabel{#1}}
  {\makelabel{$\to$\kern1pt#1}}
  {}
  {}

\def\checkeditem{%
\@inmatherr\checkeditem
\@ifnextchar [\@checkeditem{\@noitemargtrue \@checkeditem[\@itemlabel]}}
\let\@checkeditem\@item
\xpatchcmd{\@checkeditem}
  {\makelabel{#1}}
  {\makelabel{\ding{51}\kern1pt#1}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\arrowitem First item.
\item Second item.
\checkeditem Third item.
\item Fourth item.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First subitem.
  \arrowitem[($\ast$)] Second subitem.
  \checkeditem Third subitem.
\end{enumerate}
\arrowitem Fifth item.
\item Sixth item.
\item Seventh item.
\checkeditem Eighth item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to create copies of the original `\item` and `\@item` commands and then patch the copies to include the desired symbol.

(I shamelesly borrowed **azetina**'s `\myinfo` command from [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155051/3954)).

Comment: Thanks for this preliminary answer. I'm looking forward to the definitive one. Could we imagine an additional macro (to `enumitem` for instance) that would create the item in a more comprehensive way like `\newitem{listname}{\itemname}{label=$\to$\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}` ?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ah sorry, I didn't read the question correctly, +1 b.t.w

Comment: Could you elaborate on what each line of the code is doing? I would really like to understand this as it may be applicable else where.

Comment: @V.Rossetto I added to my answer an improved version; now you can easily build as many new item types as you like with a simple command `\newitem{<prefix>}{<symbol>}`, as you requested.

Comment: @azetina I was producing an improved version of the code (which now I've added to my answer); I will add some brief explanatory comments later.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Well thank you very much. I will definitely review your answer and learn from it. Its new and fresh in the business lol.

Comment: Is there some reason for the lack of indentation in the final answer? Also, it's a lot of scrolling between it and the comments ...

Comment: @V.Rossetto I forgot to mention in my previous comment, that the improved version is compatible with `enumitem` (as you also requested). You can see an example in the second code.

Comment: @SamB the only reason for not indenting some lines of the code is laziness ;-) Perhaps I'll indent the code later.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina. You guys did a great job ! Gonzalo's `\<feature>item` and azetina's `\moditem` are nicely complementary. I will use both !

Answer (score 17):

Here is an alternative MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{before=\setupmodenumerate}

\newif\ifmoditem
\newcommand{\setupmodenumerate}{%
  \global\moditemfalse
  \let\origmakelabel\makelabel
  \def\moditem##1{\global\moditemtrue\def\mesymbol{##1}\item}%
  \def\makelabel##1{%
    \origmakelabel{\ifmoditem\llap{\mesymbol\enspace}\fi##1}%
    \global\moditemfalse}%
}
\newcommand{\myinfo}{\tikz[baseline] \node (info) [anchor=base,shape=circle,draw=orange!20,inner sep=1pt,fill=orange,text=white] {\bfseries\sffamily !};}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item One
    \moditem{$\to$} Two
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Two A
            \moditem{$\to$}[($\ast$)] Two B
            \item Two C 
        \end{enumerate}
    \moditem{\ding{51}} Three
    \moditem{\myinfo} Four
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The convenience of the command defined above is that you only need one and its argument carries the special items desired. I added an example with an image using TikZ, just for fun. The `\moditem` command also works with sublevels as illustrated above.

> Note: I had asked something similar:
>   [Add an asterisk left of an enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61263/10898) and the solution given by
>   @egreg [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61264/10898).

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer. I did checked if the question had been already asked, probably with bad keywords.

Comment: @V.Rossetto Its ok. Thumbs up because you got a new answer in a different approach. So, everyone can learn the different possibilities.

Comment: Honestly I think this answer works better and should be the accepted one