# Checkboxes at ends of specific list items in outline package

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I am using the `outlines` package for multi level lists according to the second answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84172/possible-to-create-bullets-for-subitems-using-itemize-without-a-nested-list) since it was a pretty good solution and worked very well so far. However, I am wondering if it's possible to specifically have checkboxes if I change the command `\2` or `\3` to something like, say, `\2c` or `\3c`. Having the boxes on the right at the end of the line is preferable but it's OK even if it's the label or beside the label. If I were simply using `enumerate`, I could just do [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61263/add-an-asterisk-left-of-an-enumerate) but I am not sure if it's possible to tailor it to the `outlines` package. An MWE, although not too helpful in this case probably, is given.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{outlines}
\begin{document}
    \begin{outline}[enumerate]
        \1 This item should not have a check box beside it
        \2 This item should not have a check box beside it
        \2 This item should have a check box beside it
        \3 This item should have a check box beside it
    \end{outline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I defined macros `\C1`, `\C2`, `\C3`, etc. in three different ways to add checkboxes to the outline list in different ways:

- First variant: Checkboxes besides the label,
- Second variant: Checkboxes instead of the label,
- Third variant: Checkboxes at the end of the lines, this requires however to embrace the item text in curly braces.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\checkbox}{$\square$}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\C}[1]{\ifcase#1\relax\or\1\or\2\or\3\or\4\or\5\or\6\fi\checkbox}
    \begin{outline}[enumerate]
        \C1 This item should not have a check box beside it
        \C2 This item should not have a check box beside it
        \C2 This item should have a check box beside it
        \C3 This item should have a check box beside it
    \end{outline}

    \renewcommand{\C}[1]{\ifcase#1\relax\or\1[\checkbox]\or\2[\checkbox]\or\3[\checkbox]\or\4[\checkbox]\or\5[\checkbox]\or\6[\checkbox]\fi}
    \begin{outline}[enumerate]
        \C1 This item should not have a check box beside it
        \C2 This item should not have a check box beside it
        \C2 This item should have a check box beside it
        \C3 This item should have a check box beside it
    \end{outline}

    \renewcommand{\C}[2]{\ifcase#1\relax\or\1\or\2\or\3\or\4\or\5\or\6\fi#2\hfill\checkbox}
    \begin{outline}[enumerate]
        \C1{This item should not have a check box beside it}
        \C2{This item should not have a check box beside it}
        \C2{This item should have a check box beside it}
        \C3{This item should have a check box beside it}
    \end{outline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the options. Option 1 looked a bit cluttered and I'd have to change everything for option 3 since everything would now become an argument. So I think option 2 is the best for now. :)

If you want checkboxes beside all of them without choosing specific ones, is it possible to just redefine something and make the `\1, \2, \3` themselves produce the whole document with boxes?

Comment: It seems that the `\1`, `\2`, `\3` are defined only within the `outline` environment, that means there is no way of redefining them globally. One would have to alter the `outline` definition, but I don't know an easy way to do that.

Comment: K no problem. This is what I mainly needed. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Oh I thought I already did. Sorry about that. Done now. Just to confirm, there's no way to have the last option in the same format as the first two i.e. just add a `C` after the `\`, right?